# Gradle Sync Failed in Android Studio 3.1.2

Tags: java, android, gradle

[image]

How to Solve this error I amm using Android Studio Version 3.1.2 
My Build tool is 27.1.1 and I also download the build tool 21.1 for the Project in which I am working:

Comment: have you updated gradle and android gradle plugin?

Comment: remove .gradle and .idea folder then sync the project

Comment: You need to add something more. Maybe your code, maybe your gradle file. Something we can work with. Usually cleaning and rebuilding your project works, but it might be something else.

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade your Gradle version.
Edit the file as shown in the images.

[image: Gradle Folder]
[image]

See the [official Google plugin page](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin)